# Sort by a suffix in file names in dired

Tags: dired, sorting

I would like to sort the `dired` buffer by a suffix in the file names. For instance, with the following buffer content:

```
/nixos/nix/store:
total used in directory 140344 available 17530560
drwxrwxr-t 1612 root  30000  1810432 Mar  4 21:41 .
drwxr-xr-x    4 root  root      4096 Feb  4  2015 ..
dr-xr-xr-x    5 root  root      4096 Dec 31  1969 01l09wxficgyw6yhd812xzxldxrp4yma-pangomm-2.34.0
dr-xr-xr-x    5 root  root      4096 Dec 31  1969 03afp0sdvnvj9aj8k18s7ikkh4pnzlij-perl-HTTP-Message-6.06
dr-xr-xr-x    4 root  root      4096 Dec 31  1969 04yx1lnhzbiy4hkwkhnw7cw2i6zmfhf4-xmlto-0.0.26
dr-xr-xr-x    3 root  root      4096 Dec 31  1969 0534201di00hs189hzvx8gv8kxgbl2q1-unit-script
dr-xr-xr-x    2 root  root      4096 Dec 31  1969 06g99nk2q4pjq4xx3p6qw77zxmnyr5rn-kmod-blacklist-3ubuntu1
dr-xr-xr-x    4 root  root      4096 Dec 31  1969 06l8iksb8mndiis047z5f7b1zaqc1i4a-feh-2.14
dr-xr-xr-x    4 root  root      4096 Dec 31  1969 06s10661ji3s3cwsmrxc38kx856jds8i-nixos-system-jrm.no-ip.org-16.03pre77568.40c586b
dr-xr-xr-x    5 root  root      4096 Dec 31  1969 06wqzjsbjlhimn18g9ah04klhslj8b04-libkrb5-1.14
dr-xr-xr-x    7 root  root      4096 Dec 31  1969 06xdwfrhbjwhgxcsp2d2qlxhkv3ck01b-gcc-4.9.3
dr-xr-xr-x    3 root  root      4096 Dec 31  1969 079ix6d3aarvjjh83r7vcc6nk9pjcb25-mesa-noglu-11.1.1-drivers
dr-xr-xr-x    2 root  root      4096 Dec 31  1969 07k6b606sxwfib3f1srbdi1pifpb9gj3-unit-firewall.service
dr-xr-xr-x    5 root  root      4096 Dec 31  1969 07yqgv4n248xrigrnk9xn7ami5dyz3q8-lzo-2.09
dr-xr-xr-x    5 root  root      4096 Dec 31  1969 09i3xn0lbi268354l9y2nm8302qc5dhg-poppler-qt4-0.36.0
drwxr-xr-x    2 30001 30000     4096 Mar  4 20:39 09jszxa0cdd65g7yxb64fc87dq7ayy5s-jwm-s1406
dr-xr-xr-x    6 root  root      4096 Dec 31  1969 0ac359cfc4a8kw95g494z0x5vn37vrqa-libwacom-0.15
```

the file names consists of a hash sequence, followed by an `-`, followed by a suffix (the really interesting part of the name). I want to sort by this last part.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dired relies on the `ls` command to do the listing and the sorting. The options for sorting are limited to what the `ls` command can do (via switches added with `C-u s` (`dired-sort-toggle-or-edit`)). On ELPA, I can find packages that make it easier to change the `ls` switches, but not packages that allow the sort order to be customized.

It seems that the only way to customize the sort order is to invoke your own program instead of `ls`. The program invoked is determined by the [`insert-directory-program`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Contents-of-Directories.html#index-insert_002ddirectory_002dprogram) variable. So you could set it locally to a wrapper that calls `ls` and then sorts the result. Here's a shell wrapper you can use; put that in a script, make it executable (`M-x chmod` with the permission `+x`), and set `insert-directory-program` to that locally.

```
#!/bin/sh
ls_output=$(ls "$@")
nl='
'
echo "${ls_output%%"$nl"*}" # The total... line
ls_output=${ls_output#*"$nl"}
# Isolate the //DIRED stuff, which must go last
case "$ls_output" in
  *"$nl//DIRED"*)
    dired_stuff="//DIRED${ls_output##*"$nl//DIRED"}$nl"
    ls_output="${ls_output%"$nl//DIRED"*}";;
  *) dired_stuff=;;
esac
# Now sort, ignoring the first 8 fields (metadata) and the first 33 characters of the 9th field
printf '%s\n' "$ls_output" | sort -k 9.34
printf '%s' "$dired_stuff"
```

Then

```
M-: (make-local-variable 'insert-directory-program) RET
M-: (setq insert-directory-program "/path/to/wrapper") RET
```

Comment: It seems that `echo "${ls_output%"$nl"*}" ` is not selecting the `total...` line as expected. It is outputting the full list.

Comment: @Romildo Stripping away the last line, actually, instead of stripping all lines but the first. I've fixed this and a couple other problems.